# After creating JTextField dynamically, how do i use getText()?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have referred to this [I want to add a JLabel and Text box dynamically by clicking add button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098017/i-want-to-add-a-jlabel-and-text-box-dynamically-by-clicking-add-button) to create my `JTextField` dynamically.

But how do i use the `getText()` to retrieve the text from each of the textfields individually?

```
public class CreateGuestForm2 {

private JFrame jFrame = null;  //  @jve:decl-index=0:visual-constraint="111,10"
private JPanel jContentPane = null;
private int indexer = 1;  //  @jve:decl-index=0:
private List<JLabel> listOfLabels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();  //  @jve:decl-index=0:
private List<JTextField> listOfTextFields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();  //  @jve:decl-index=0:
private JButton jButtonAdd = null;
private JPanel jPanel = null;
private GridBagConstraints textFieldConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();  //  @jve:decl-index=0:
private GridBagConstraints labelConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();//  @jve:decl-index=0:
private JButton jButtonCreate = null;
private JButton jButtonHelp = null;
String textFields = null;



/**
 * This method initializes jFrame   
 *  
 * @return javax.swing.JFrame   
 */
private JFrame getJFrame() {
    if (jFrame == null) {
        jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        jFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        jFrame.setTitle("Create Guest Form");
        jFrame.setSize(new Dimension(800, 582));
        jFrame.setContentPane(getJContentPane());
        jFrame.pack();
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
    return jFrame;
}


/**
 * This method initializes jContentPane 
 *  
 * @return javax.swing.JPanel   
 */
private JPanel getJContentPane() {
    if (jContentPane == null) {
        jContentPane = new JPanel();
        jContentPane.setLayout(null);
        jContentPane.add(getJButtonAdd(), null);
        jContentPane.add(getJPanel(), null);
        jContentPane.add(getJButtonCreate(), null);
        jContentPane.add(getJButtonHelp(), null);
        jContentPane.add(getJPanel(), null);
        jContentPane.add(getJPanel(), null);
    }
    return jContentPane;
}


/**
 * This method initializes jButtonAdd   
 *  
 * @return javax.swing.JButton  
 */
private JButton getJButtonAdd() {
    if (jButtonAdd == null) {
        jButtonAdd = new JButton();
        jButtonAdd.setText("Add a guest");
        jButtonAdd.setBounds(new Rectangle(14, 45, 111, 24));
        jButtonAdd.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("actionPerformed()"); 
                addGuest(e);
            }
        });
    }
    return jButtonAdd;
}

public void addGuest(ActionEvent e){
    // Clear panel
    jPanel.removeAll();

    // Create label and text field
    JTextField jTextField = new JTextField();
    textFields = jTextField.getText();
    jTextField.setSize(100, 200);
    listOfTextFields.add(jTextField);
    listOfLabels.add(new JLabel("Guest " + indexer));

    // Add labels and text fields
    for(int i = 0; i < indexer; i++)
    {
        // Text field constraints
        textFieldConstraints.gridx = 1;
        textFieldConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        textFieldConstraints.weightx = 0.5;
        textFieldConstraints.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        textFieldConstraints.gridy = i;

        // Label constraints
        labelConstraints.gridx = 0;
        labelConstraints.gridy = i;
        labelConstraints.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);

        // Add them to panel
        jPanel.add(listOfLabels.get(i), labelConstraints);
        jPanel.add(listOfTextFields.get(i), textFieldConstraints);


    }

    // Align components top-to-bottom
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = indexer;
    c.weighty = 1;
    jPanel.add(new JLabel(), c);
    indexer++;
    jPanel.updateUI();
}
/**
 * This method initializes jPanel   
 *  
 * @return javax.swing.JPanel   
 */
private JPanel getJPanel() {
    if (jPanel == null) {
        jPanel = new JPanel();
        jPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        jPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,600));
        jPanel.setBounds(new Rectangle(14, 76, 759, 413));
        jPanel.setBorder(LineBorder.createBlackLineBorder());


    }
    return jPanel;
}

/**
 * This method initializes jButtonCreate    
 *  
 * @return javax.swing.JButton  
 */
private JButton getJButtonCreate() {
    if (jButtonCreate == null) {
        jButtonCreate = new JButton();
        jButtonCreate.setText("Create");
        jButtonCreate.setBounds(new Rectangle(681, 505, 93, 27));
        jButtonCreate.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("actionPerformed()"); // TODO Auto-generated Event stub actionPerformed()
                createGuest(e);
            }
        });
    }
    return jButtonCreate;
}

public void createGuest(ActionEvent e){
    String record = textFields;
    GuestControl gCreate = new GuestControl();
    if(gCreate.processCreateGuest2(record)){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Guest record created successfully");
        getJFrame().dispose();
    }
    else
    {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Guest not created, please try again");

    }

}
}
```

ps: i am doing this for a school project on creating a guest form

Answer (score 4):

Try this....

**When you create a JTextField dynamically give it an Name**, its like an id. Using this name you can refer to it...

```
for (int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++){

    newButton.setName(String.valueOf(i));

}
```

**Edited:**

```
   nbutt.putClientProperty("id", Integer.valueOf(i));
```

**Now to fetch value from proerty map.**

```
Object mProperty = nbutt.getClientProperty("id");

   if (mProperty instanceof Integer) {

      int i = ((Integer)mProperty);

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

`listOfTextFields.get(i).getText()` should work.

Comment: after using listOfTextFields.get(i).getText() in my for loop, how to i get the information from the jButtonCreate

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. But basically if you want to pass any information you could either pass the information as method parameter, or you could put it as a field in class.